# I can access the site over SSH but not via HTTP?

Tags: wordpress, server, amazon-lightsail

I have a wordpress instance on AWS Lightsail.

I can access the VPS via SSH but it won't load over HTTP??

Here is what my error_log is saying:
[Mon May 13 10:58:14.946209 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 2780:tid 139711779657472] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /opt/bitnami/php/var/run/wordpress.sock (wordpress-fpm) failed
[Mon May 13 10:58:14.946221 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2780:tid 139711779657472] [client 78.46.85.236:11708] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS

I have checked all services are running. i.e apache2, mySQL & PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isn't Apache complaining. Apache is running just fine and cannot reverse proxy to the unix socket `wordpress-fpm`. It is likely that there is an issue where the php-fpm service is either not started, or your app is erroring. there should be a separate php error log and apache error log (this looks like the apache one). of course try the below commands to make sure your app is running at all.

```
$ sudo service php-fpm start # <- start it
$ sudo service php-fpm stop # <- stop it
$ sudo service php-fpm restart # <- restart it
$ sudo service php-fpm reload # <- reload it
```